# Border flickering issue in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an strange problem using two borders. I use them to display video from Lync 2010. But to make it more like normal video chat, i like to have them on top of each other. But then i trie to do it. Then the rear video is moving the border is flickering wild. 
[image: The layout of the two borders]

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "flickering wild"? It is difficult to tell from the image provided. Are the contents, i.e. the video, resizing or that the borders appear to blurred as you move the window?

Comment: It's hard to explain. But then the video on the back has movements in it, the front video starts flikering. Like there's an problem with the framework.

Comment: I wonder if us of an doublebuffer, will solve the problem.

Comment: With the images it a lot easier to understand what the problem is; it essentially an airspace issue as **both** videos streams are using accelerated rendering and thus are wanting to render last. As both trying to render into the same Z space (where Z is depth) they are "flickering". In game development we call this Z-space fighting. It is possible to solve by writing custom controls.

Comment: Should an Canvas control not fix the problem. If i also put an Canvas.ZIndex="" into the two borders? But why doesn't it do that?

Comment: You won't be able to change the z depth using a canvas. The video is being render at the top-most level by Windows/DirectX. The solution is get a `VisualBrush` of the video stream so that it can take part in the WPF layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was made by Dennis Roche "You won't be able to change the z depth using a canvas. The video is being render at the top-most level by Windows/DirectX. The solution is get a VisualBrush of the video stream so that it can take part in the WPF layout. "